# Insert logo at the top of my project xamarin form ios, android

Tags: xamarin

I have a project that this without logo written only the name of the company, as the image below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NoqX9.png)

now I want to put the company logo on the top of my project, to stay with a designer perfect, as you can see in the image below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLWya.jpg)

I'm using xamarin forms and developing app for android and ios, how can I do this in my project? does anyone have any examples?

EDIT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="projeto.Views.home"
    x:Name="Name"
    Title="Name" Icon="">
```

Comment: I suggest following some examples on creating a basic app with Xamarin.Forms as you may miss some basic understanding of UI components - [Getting Started With Xamarin.Forms](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/getting-started/)
We could paste a bunch of code but you wouldn't understand why, and there are also several ways of doing these things.

Comment: I already have my project ready, I'm just not finding a way for me to do it correctly, you can put the commands there that I can un-check

Comment: Well, what have you tried? Give us some context of your project. Are you using xaml or code-behind to construct your UI? Are you using Xamarin.Forms or Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS projects instead?

Comment: Are you using Xamarin.Forms or Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS projects instead?  Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS and I have the portable which makes integration with the project

Comment: You are then using Xamarin.Forms. Please give us some code so we can see what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a rough layout of what your page could look like:

```
<ContentPage
xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
x:Class="projeto.Views.home"
x:Name="Name"
Title="Name" Icon="">

    <!--Content page may only have one child element-->
    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Orientation="Vertical">
        <Image Source="CompanyLogo.png" AspectRatio="AspectFit"/>
        <StackLayout>
            <!--Other content--->
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Note that this very basic approach is one of several. You need to familiarise yourself with xaml and the different components you could use to achieve certain things.

Comment: Okay, so that's right, too. But not the way I thought it yet. I wanted him to get stuck, so you informed me if I rolled down the logo will fade